# Migration of old XP hdd to VM

Tags: windows, migration, virtual-machine

I have old PC with 80GB hdd and Win XP. I want to backup it in VM but not sure whether exists "easy solution". Once I tried to make archive with Ghost, then restored it in VM (Virtual PC) on virtual HDD with equal size. Unfortunately at the end the virtual system did not run... Any ideas or tricks for similar task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can backup to a VM with VirtualBox, VMWare, VirtualPC and probably some other Virtual Machine environments.

Have a look here [Convert your PC to VM](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/convert-use-your-physical-machine-in-vmware-virtualbox-virtual-pc/)

Another thing you can do is use an app like [Disk2Vhd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) to create a virtual disk and then attach it to Hyper V or VirtualBox.